# VBA Index Match Run-time error'13': Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch on the following code. From what I understand about this error it seems to be caused by having two types of variables in a formula. This is somewhat true for me, as my index match function concatinates cells with numbers and cells with text to return a number. I've tried to format the numbers as text, but keep getting the same error. Does it seem like this is the issue? If so, does anyone know a workaround for this/ different way of doing what I'm trying to do here? Thanks!

```
Sub Lookup2()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lookUp1Sht As Worksheet
    Dim lookUp2Sht As Worksheet
    Dim lookUp2Rng As Range
    Dim val1 As Variant

    Set lookUp1Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New") 
    Set lookUp2Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input")
    Set lookUp2Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("comp").Range("A1:C136")

    For Each cell In Range("CaliforniaL") 
        With cell '
            Select Case True
                Case IsNumeric(.Value) 
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = CDbl(.Value)
                Case Else
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = (Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(lookUp2Sht.Range("K:K"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(cell.Value & cell.Offset(0, -3), lookUp2Sht.Range("A:A") & lookUp2Sht.Range("H:H"), 0)))
            End Select
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line specifically errors out? If you hover over things while in break mode, can you see the values of all your functions/variables to figure out which one is returning a bum value?

Comment: It's on the line that has the Index Match function.When I hover over each part of the line it says .Offset (0,1).Value = Empty

Comment: For Each cell in Range().Cells

Comment: The part of your code saying `lookUp2Sht.Range("A:A") & lookUp2Sht.Range("H:H")` looks "wrong".  I'm not sure how Excel is going to interpret an attempt to concatenate two ranges of complete columns.  Just checked, and `Match` can't cope with two columns - it really doesn't make much sense looking for a value in two columns at once.

Comment: I **think** I have worked out what you are trying to do with your `Match` - are you trying to find the location where `cell.Value` exists in `lookUp2Sht.Range("A:A")` AND, at the same time, `cell.Offset(0, -3)` exists in `lookUp2Sht.Range("H:H")`?

Comment: For each row in my range, I want to use the value in that row, columns A&L, to return the value on the "input" sheet in column K.  The values on the "New" sheet in rows A&L should match exactly one row on the "input" sheet in columns A&H. I need two different pieces of information to return the proper value, as either one alone will return multiple values. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a function that does a "double" match.  (There was probably one available in Excel, but I was too lazy to look for it.)  Using it, and based on some clarifications in your comments, your code can be re-written as follows:

```
Sub Lookup2()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lookUp1Sht As Worksheet
    Dim lookUp2Sht As Worksheet
    Dim lookUp2Rng As Range
    Dim val1 As Variant

    Set lookUp1Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New")
    Set lookUp2Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("input")
    Set lookUp2Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("comp").Range("A1:C136")

    For Each cell In Range("CaliforniaL")
        With cell
            If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = CDbl(.Value)
            Else
                val1 = DoubleMatch(lookUp1Sht.Cells(.Row, "A").Value, lookUp2Sht.Range("A:A"), _
                                   lookUp1Sht.Cells(.Row, "L").Value, lookUp2Sht.Range("H:H"))
                If IsError(val1) Then
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = val1
                Else
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = lookUp2Sht.Cells(val1, "K").Value
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Function DoubleMatch(Key1 As Variant, Range1 As Range, Key2 As Variant, Range2 As Range) As Variant
    'This function only performs an "Exact Match"
    If Range1.Rows.Count <> Range2.Rows.Count Then
        DoubleMatch = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Range1.Columns.Count > 1 Or Range2.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        DoubleMatch = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim c As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim address1 As String
    With Range1
        Set c = .Find(What:=Key1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            DoubleMatch = CVErr(xlErrNA)
            Exit Function
        End If
        address1 = c.Address

        Do
            r = c.Row - Range1.Row + 1
            If Key2 = Range2(r, 1).Value Then
                DoubleMatch = r
                Exit Function
            End If
            Set c = .Find(What:=Key1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, After:=c)
            If c Is Nothing Then
                DoubleMatch = CVErr(xlErrNA)
                Exit Function
            End If
            If c.Address = address1 Then
                DoubleMatch = CVErr(xlErrNA)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Loop
    End With
    DoubleMatch = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the issue is with this part:

```
cell.Value & cell.Offset(0, -3)
```

`cell.value` is returning the data in the cell, while `cell.Offset` [returns a range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Since the `Match` function needs a `lookup_value`, and since you can't concatenate a value and a range object, this will cause an error. In fact, you can't concatenate ranges at all, so the 2nd argument of your match function will also fail:

```
lookUp2Sht.Range("A:A") & lookUp2Sht.Range("H:H")
```

If you put these formulas in a cell on a worksheet (eg, `=match(A2 & d2, A:A & H:H, 0)` you'll see that they won't work.

I've never quite seen the value in using worksheet functions in VBA code. I'm not saying there isn't value, just that I've never seen a need.

Comment: `cell.Value & cell.Offset(0, -3)` would be valid - the default property of the cell object (at least in that situation) is its Value, so `cell.Offset(0, -3)` is equivalent to `cell.Offset(0, -3).Value`.

Comment: I just used worksheet functions because I'm new to VBA and that's what I'm familiar with. Do you know of a different way to achieve this without using worksheet functions?